# Why can't I style tags via css when I used them on a javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to style my div and button as well, using css. But after including a javascript code for my button wherein its function is to show and hide my div form. Whatever I type on my css doesn't seem to affect the style of my div anymore.

What do I have to do?

Here is my code:

```js
var theForm = document.getElementById('show-form').style.visibility = 'hidden';
var theButton = document.getElementById('show-button');
var thexButton = document.getElementById('hide-button');

thexButton.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('show-form').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

theButton.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('show-form').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```css
.hide-button {
  background: red;
}

.form-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button id="show-button">Add Report</button>
<div class="form-wrapper" id="show-form">
  <button id="hide-button">X</button>
  <form action="add.php" method="post">
    <label>File Name: </label> <input class="input2" type="text" required><br>
    <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" name="insert" value="Save">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It does affect your style. If you want to see it more visibly, add `background-color: red;` to your `.form-wrapper` and you'll notice it

Comment: It sure does run here on the snippet. But why is it not running on my computer. BTW I open my webpage using xampp.

Comment: If this snippet is working, but your local page does not, then there must be a significant difference in the markup between the two. Would you mind posting the exact markup from your local page; the one that does not work?

Answer (score 2):

As your button has the id of hide-button but in css you select it as .hide-button so Change following code

```
.hide-button {
  background: red;
}
```

to this

```
#hide-button {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! But I have already done that. And it still does not affect the background color of my button. IDK why, maybe my localhost server?

Comment: May be...but it works fine on my system..hard refresh your browser tab may be that solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the hide button.
You used class in the css but in the HTML you use id.
So here's the fix.

```js
var theForm = document.getElementById('show-form').style.visibility = 'hidden';
var theButton = document.getElementById('show-button');
var thexButton = document.getElementById('hide-button');

thexButton.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('show-form').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

theButton.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('show-form').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```css
#hide-button {
  background: red;
}

.form-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button id="show-button">Add Report</button>
<div class="form-wrapper" id="show-form">
  <button id="hide-button">X</button>
  <form action="add.php" method="post">
    <label>File Name: </label> <input class="input2" type="text" required><br>
    <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" name="insert" value="Save">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate! But I have already done that. And it still does not affect the background color of my button. IDK why, maybe my localhost server?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I used this method and it ran. Maybe my system is the problem.

```
.form-wrapper .hide-btn {
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: This sounds more like conflicting styles in your own CSS, if it suddenly works when you increase the specificity of a selector.